# BehaviorSubject delete bug

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have a simple select all and select one item. The error happens when selectAll is clicked then selectone is clicked next. The original list also gets deleted. What can I do to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

TS code:

```
    original$: BehaviorSubject<SomeObject[]> = new BehaviorSubject<SomeObject[]>([]);
    selected$: BehaviorSubject<SomeObject[]> = new BehaviorSubject<SomeObject[]>([]);
    
    selectAll(event)
    {        
        if(event.target.checked){
         this.selected$.next(this.original$.value);         
        }
        else{
          this.selected$ = new BehaviorSubject<SomeObject[]>([]);
        }    
    }
    
    selectone(event, obj) {
        let list = this.selected$.value;
        if (event.target.checked) {
          list.push(obj);
        }
        else {          
    
        //error is here, even item in orginal$ is removed  
          _.remove(list, x => x.id == obj.id);  
        }    
        this.selected$.next(list);
      }
```

HTML code:

```
<input id="select All" type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll($event)">

<tr *ngFor="let x of original$ | async; let index = index">                 
  <input id="{{ index }}" type="checkbox"  (change)="selectone($event, x)" />       
</tr>
```

Comment: The problem may be due to behavior subjects storing array values. `this.selected$.next(this.original$.value)` assigns the same array pointer to both behavior subjects. Instead, do `this.selected$.next([...this.original$.value])` which assigns `selected$` a copy of `original$`

Comment: @Drenai Thanks that's what I just did :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Due to behavior subjects storing array values:

`this.selected$.next(this.original$.value)`

assigns the same array pointer to both behavior subjects.

**Solution:**

Instead, do

`this.selected$.next([...this.original$.value])`

which assigns selected$ a copy of original$